# Exclude word between other two as regexp

Tags: java, regex, text

I have the pattern

```
\\bi\\b[^.!?]{0,10}\\bhate
```

which matches string only in one sentence (not divided by `.!?` ). But it also matches the opposite sense with `not` between two words. How to exclude such occurences of `not` in between two words with maximum distance of 10 between them.

Now it matches: `i do not hate`. I would like to exclude that and leave only matches such as `i do hate` or `i hate`.

Comment: This `[^.!?]{0,10}` has to be between `{1,10}`

Comment: `\bi\b(?:(?!\bnot\b)[^.!?]){1,10}\bhate\b`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BnOpLp/1).

Answer (score 1):

You would exclude *not* in a negative assertion
tailored to the length of NOT within  the first 10 characters.
I.e. the range is `10 - length('not')` or {0,7}

`\bi\b(?!.{0,7}not)[^.!?]{0,10}\bhate`

https://regex101.com/r/vdqBQX/1

```
 \b i \b                       # 'i'
 (?! .{0,7} not )              # Here, exclude 'not' if within the first 7 characters     
 [^.!?]{0,10} \b               # O - 10 characters within this negated class
 hate
```

Comment: thanx for such details, but length of 3 digits isn't so much matter here for me. Just needed to exclude negation

Comment: @SergeyAleshkinAlyoshkin - Did I make too big of a deal about the length of `'not'` ? Sorry, but you made a big deal of the length between words `between two words with maximum distance 10 between them`. Maybe you don't care so much about the _length_ between words.  I guess you could just do `^i (?!.*not).*hate$`